# I want to write a list comprehension to determine the length of each word except 'the' word. I have no idea how to get rid 'the' word

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook

Here is my sample code:

Code:

```
sentence = "MMU is the best university in Malaysia"
word_lengths = [len(n) for n in sentence.split()]
word_lengths
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 3, 4, 10, 2, 8]
```

Expected output:

```
[3, 2, 4, 10, 2, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you would like to have this:

```
word_lengths = [len(n) for n in sentence.split() if n != "the"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
word_lengths = [len(n) for n in sentence.split() if n != 'the']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the split mechanism
try the following

```
sentence = "MMU is the best university in Malaysia"
```

I don't understand you but I guess you want to get the length of the word other than 'the'

```
length = [len(word) for word in sentence.split(" ") if word != 'the']
```